# Facebook Pixel No Catalog Events

Tags: facebook, events, ads, pixel, catalog

I have Pixel installed on my website. My Catalog is updated. Pixel Helper is showing events with a blue check.  Event manager is showing all the events with right parameters. Still there are no events in Catalog Manager->Events Tab. My Pixel is connected to the catalog.

Catalog Events:

[image: Catalog Events]

Check Standard Code on Catalog Event:

[image: Check Standard Code on Catalog Event]

Events Manager Showing events:

[image: Events Manager Showing events]

Pixel Helper Showing Events:

[image: Pixel Helper Showing Events]

Answer (score 1):

Facebook says that it might take upto 24hrs for the pixel to update or setup. I waited for the given time but still had no events showing but apparently it can take even more time so, I finally started seeing those events in Catalog Manager after 3 days of initial setup.